# Wordpress function wp_set_object_term not setting terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I'm trying to insert a new post into wordpress the post is a woocommerce product but im trying to set the terms to what is needed. I do get good return values but its not inserting into the Database.

My Code :

```
    // Set the page ID so that we know the page was created successfully
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'        =>  $_POST['post_title'],
        'post_author'       =>  $_POST['current_user'],
        'post_content'      =>  '',
        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_status'       =>  'pending',
        'post_type'         =>  'product'
    );
    $my_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post, true);

    var_dump($my_post_id);

    if($my_post_id == 0) {
        //Obviously something went wrong
    } else {
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_start_price', $_POST['prijs_start']);
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_type', 'reverse');
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_item_condition', 'new');
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_dates_from', $_POST['start_auction']);
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_dates_to', $_POST['end_auction']);
        add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_auction_bid_increment', '25');
        $tvar = wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, 'auction' ,'product_type');
        $tvar2 = wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, intval($_POST['cat_id']), 'product_cat');
        if(is_wp_error( $tvar )){
            echo 'ERROR';
        }
        var_dump($tvar);
        var_dump($tvar2);
    }
```

What $tvar and $tvar2 returns :

```
int(908) //Post ID
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "48" } //The Auction TermID
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "57" } //The Category TermID
```

Still its not being set in the database any idea's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not noticing any reference to `$new_post_id` in your code, hence the following is incorrect

```
$tvar = wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, 'auction' ,'product_type');
$tvar2 = wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, intval($_POST['cat_id']), 'product_cat');
```

Should be

```
$tvar = wp_set_object_terms($my_post_id, 'auction' ,'product_type');
$tvar2 = wp_set_object_terms($my_post_id, intval($_POST['cat_id']), 'product_cat');
```

Comment: arghh dammit your right aswell, Looked over it about a 100 times and couldn't find that :D Thanks

Comment: I know and understand the feeling :) Glad I could help.